# custom encoder for Data

Tags: swift, encoding

I got a series of data as bytes, I tried to encode it

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dataEncodingStrategy = .deferredToData
let encodedData = try encoder.encode(data)
let data = encodedData.compactMap { $0 }
```

my data is looks like that:

```
[ 91,91,48, 44, 49, 57, 51, ..., 49, 44, 48, 93, 93]
```

It works, but the outcome is not what I expected (the numbers inside the `data.element` are different), then I tried to change the encoding strategy.

```
encoder64.dataEncodingStrategy = .base64
let data = encodedData.compactMap { $0 }
[91, 34, 65, 77, 72, ..., 65, 61, 61, 34, 93]
```

Then I have a different results, but still not is the what that I expected.

there is another custom encoding strategy, could you please give me some example of this custom strategy that I can test another forms to compare the results.

the example data that I expected is like :

```
[ 0, 193, 193, 193, 193, 72, 20, 193, ..., 255, 91, 0]
```

the 0 in the beginning and in the end is so important to me.

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're expecting vs. what you're seeing in practice?

Comment: Thanks @ItaiFerber, I updated the first post

Comment: What is the purpose of `compactMap`?

Comment: @Robertkont How are you generating the data that you're expecting? Is it something that you're comparing against produced on another platform? Keep in mind that the data that `JSONEncoder` produces is UTF-8 JSON, so it's not possible for the data to contain `0`s verbatim like this. Is the expected data actual JSON?

Comment: Thanks  @ItaiFerber, the correct form of data is generated somewhere else and I tried to replace it with the app. I should POST the correct form of the data to an endpoint

Comment: @Robertkont It would be easy to add zeros (prefix and suffix) to the data returned in your last question

Comment: @Robertkont I think your question it is not clear. Can you be more explicit about what is the input, the expected output and why?

Comment: Btw your code doesn't make any sense you get your encodedData from encoding data and the next line you are defining data again. So you code wouldn't even compile. Please edit your question and post a [mcve]

Comment: And no need to use compactMap to convert your data to bytes. `let bytes = Array(data)`

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct.

The `JSONEncoder` creates a JSON string from the data and `compactMap` maps each character to its `UInt8` value

```
91 is [
91 is [
48 is 0
44 is , 
49 is 1 
57 is 9 
51 is 3 
...
49 is 1 
44 is ,
48 is 0
93 is ]
93 is ]
```

And consider the different representations: 91hex is 145dec

Comment: Thank you so much @vadian, how I can covert the outcome to have something similar the expected outcome?

Comment: What is the *expected outcome*? You example data is ambiguous.

Comment: dear @vadian, to ability to POST data with example structure of [ 0, 193, 193, 193, 193, ..., 255, 91, 0]

Comment: @Robertkont `[ 0, 193, 193, 193, 193, ..., 255, 91, 0] is too vague` what 193, 193, 193, 193 represents?